# Read from pastebin in C++

Tags: c++, http, pastebin

I'm creating a little script for xbox 360 using c++ and so i can't use any libaries like libcurl to read of a website and i was wondering if any of you guys would know how i could code this C# piece of code:

```
public static string[] readFromPaste(string string_3)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create(string_3).GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
            string str = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] strArray = new string[0xff];
            for (int i = 0; (str = reader.ReadLine()) != null; i++)
            {
                string[] strArray2 = str.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray());
                strArray[i] = strArray2[0];
            }
            return strArray;
        }
```

in C++ **without** using any Libaries like libcurl? I know it is possible i just can't figure it out tho! Any help is greatly appreciated since im stuck on how to read of a website in c++ on a xbox script for so so long!

Comment: This isn't a "do it for me please" place! Besides, xbox is probably architected such that you need to use the platform's API for this, which .NET can do but "bare" C++ cannot. Why don't you use the proper language for the job?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

C++.Net/CLI Console Application:

You are on the right track with `StreamReader()`. I made two solution versions using `StreamReader()`.

Version one: This code opens a `WebClient()` and then pipes data through it into `StreamReader()` and stores the result line by line in an indexed string array.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::IO;

int main()
{
    array<String^>^ linefrompastebin = gcnew array<String^>(100000);
    int i = 0;
    int maxLines = 0;

    String^  url = "http://pastebin.com/f7KKzVyf";
    WebClient^ client = gcnew WebClient;
    Stream^ data = client->OpenRead(url);

    Console::WriteLine("Reading HTML at :  " + url + " \n\n");
    Stream^ stream = client->OpenRead(url);
    StreamReader^ reader = gcnew StreamReader(data);

    linefrompastebin[0] = "";

    //Store lines from HTML into string
    while ((linefrompastebin[i] = reader->ReadLine()) != nullptr){
        i++;
    }
    maxLines = i;

    for (i = 0; i < maxLines; i++){
        Console::WriteLine("Line " + i + " = " + linefrompastebin[i]);
    }

    Console::WriteLine("\n\n");
    Console::ReadLine();

    return 0;
}
```

Version two:
This code opens a `WebClient()` and then pipes data through it into `StreamReader()` and stores the result in only one single string object and not in a string array.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#using <System.dll>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::IO;
int main()
{

    WebClient^ WebBrowserClient = gcnew WebClient;
    String^  url = "http://pastebin.com/f7KKzVyf";
    WebBrowserClient->Headers->Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    Stream^ data = WebBrowserClient->OpenRead(url );
    StreamReader^ reader = gcnew StreamReader(data);
    String^ s = reader->ReadToEnd();
    Console::WriteLine(s);
    data->Close();
    reader->Close();

    Console::ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: ive already "developed" apps in C# for Xbox, that's not the problem, the problem is how i can read of a pastebin raw paste using C++!

Comment: that code seems to be what im looking for, but the project is for xbox so thing like Webclient cant be implemented... i get all those errors... http://imgur.com/3gkSDQx

Comment: What exactly are you using to - visual studio 2015 or xna gamestudio or whatever , so i can replicate your conditions. On Xbox you are limited to what XNA provides to you which is a subset of the .NET framework and the only network access is through the Xbox Live APIs.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I also implemented the winsock.h class in my project as a external reference since i cant access it to the pc libaries. I also have 2 apis of xbox

Comment: Pastebin detecting too many requests and blocking scripts